# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-series, fresnel-integrals

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
How to solve this trigonometric integral? I can't find any solutions. Some books suggest to use Fresnel integral. I would be grateful if you could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral is related to Fresnel S integral to which you arrive using the change of variable suggested by 7raisen7.

For your problem, the antiderivative is  $$\sqrt{\pi } S\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)$$ and the integral $$\sqrt{\pi } S\left(\sqrt{2}\right)=1.2654828001827241355...$$

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: @kilik. You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:
$$
t=\sqrt{x}\Rightarrow dx=2tdt
$$
So that you have to solve:
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\frac{\sin(2t^2)}{t}2tdt=2\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\sin(2t^2)dt,
$$
then it should be easy enough.

Comment: The last integral is $\int \sin (2t^2)dt$. There is no factor $t$.

Comment: Edited, sorry, copy/paste typo!

Comment: it doesn't work since when you sub in the limits, it tends to infinity. The answer cannot be that as I am calculating the value for the skin friction drag on an airfoil. I have also tried integration by parts but no luck with that too since it diverges.

Comment: There is not closed form for the last integral as well...

Comment: See my edited answer, you'll find the integration limits. Moreover, how can it diverge if it is only a sinus integration in a finite interval?